# Customaze API Attribute

Tags: asp.net-core

Good afternoon, I study .NET CORE. How to create a custom attribute for the controller API? I want to allow requests to controllers from certain ip addresses.

In ASP. Net framework I created a custom attribute inheriting from "AuthorizeAttribute" then I just add my attribute to my controller.

I want that controller work from specific Ip address

Comment: I'm not sure overriding is the `AuthorizationAttribute` is the better way to achieve what you're trying to do. Did you consider using an authorization policy instead ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create attribute inherited from `IAuthorizationFilter` to have similar behavior to previous `ASP.NET` framework.

```cs
public class IpAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (/*ip not allowed*/)
        {
            //return 401 Unauthorized
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

However, Microsoft recommends [policy based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.2) authorization for `ASP.NET Core`.